# How to use ViewChildren with different children?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html

How to make a universal wrapper for the component?

I need to be able to wrap any component with my wrapper.

For example:

child.html

```
...
<h2>child<h2>
...
```

wrapper.dart

```
...
<h1><child><child><h1>
...
```

result html:

```
<h1><h2>child<h2><h1>
```

I found [ViewChildren](https://webdev.dartlang.org/api/angular/angular/ViewChild-class), but static components are indicated here, in my case I cannot know who will be the child.

How can I do that? Can you set an example?

Answer (score 0):

For that you'll want to use ng-content. https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/lifecycle-hooks#content-projection

For example:

child.html

```
<h2>child<h2>
```

wrapper.dart

```
<h1><ng-content></ng-content><h1>
```

parent html:

```
<wrapper><child></child></wrapper>
```

Comment: Show an example of how to do it correctly. I need to be able to use something like this:<parent-component>
    <child-component></child-component>
</parent-component>
I made a test repository: https://github.com/StekolschikovV/dart-test-child

Comment: Added an example.